# Source several files at once with psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

I want to execute several sql scripts sequentially with `psql` as a single transaction to set up my database schema. What is the best way to do this? In the past I know I had a master script that I ran `psql` against that included the other files however I don't remember the syntax of this script.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Your script could look like this:

```
BEGIN;
\i file1.sql
\i file2.sql
COMMIT;
```

Or you could do something like this:

```
cat file1.sql file2.sql | psql -1 -f -
```

Comment: [Understanding pipes in the shell](http://superuser.com/q/178796/59284) helped me get the last command.

Comment: Your example with BEGIN; COMMIT; does not work, you need semi-columns at the end of each `\i` line:

Answer (score 3):

You could also simply do:

```
psql -c "BEGIN TRANSACTION;" -f file1.sql -f file2.sql -c "COMMIT;"
```

This will actually run in four different chained parts through the `psql`:

1. Run `BEGIN TRANSACTION;`
2. Run `file1.sql`
3. Run `file2.sql`
4. Run `COMMIT;`

Answer (score 0):

I did it using find in unix / linux with the path to the file sql past with rep_sql parameter with "read" instruction :

```
find -P ${rep_sql} -type f -name *.sql -execdir psql -d "mabase" -f {} +
```

It says: find not following links files whatever the name with ext as «.sql» and execute in the directory of the file psql working with mabase and execute the file found.